# Ubuntu 13.10 Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Bluetooth Mouse issue

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, microsoft

First of all, everything works normally on the same computer with Windows 8.1. If I connect the mouse to Ubuntu 13.10 manually (pressing special button on the device), it enables and works properly. But after reboot it doesn't connect automatically and I have to do it by pressing the button. So, it seems I need to provide some feedback between the mouse and Ubuntu, but how should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of blueman Bluetooth manager completely solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Both os need have the same bluetooth name and use same key (last working one)

On windows key is stored at

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Keys\yor_mac_address

On Linux

/var/lib/bluetooth/yor_mac_address/linkkeys

To read or edit windows 7 key need "PSEXEC" to exec regedit as system account.

https://nullroute.eu.org/~grawity/bluetooth-key-sharing.html